# Energy conversion, conversion to kinetic energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

It's a simple but confusing issue for me.

Let's think about the following situations.

The same person (It has exactly the same physical properties.) pushes an object of M1 and M2 (M1 and M2 have different values.) in mass by the same force and distance, respectively.

For an external stationary observer, that person's velocity will be the same. The objects that the person pushes will have different velocities because they have different masses.

You can think of this situation as the energy stored in a person is converted into kinetic energy.

I thought that if someone pushed objects of different mass by the same force and distance, the energy consumed by the person would be the same. However, in the above case, the sum of kinetic energy is different if the mass of the object pushed by a person is different.

Is it true that the energy consumed by the person is different?

Comment: Why do you think that the energies are different?

Comment: @Martin'Kvík'Baláž I'm not sure what I'm confusing. I don't have much physical knowledge, so it's not easy to calculate for me. My "guess" is that even if the ground's geostationary observer sees the same human velocity, the sum of the kinetic energies of the objects pushed by the human being may vary if the mass is different. As a result, I thought that the energy consumed by humans was different because it was the kinetic energy of humans + the kinetic energy of objects.

Comment: what makes you think the two persons velocities will be the same?

Comment: @NOHWHIREA Even without calculating anything, there should be a reason why you would think they are different. Kinetic energy is a function of mass and speed. If both are equal for both objects, then their kinetic energy must be equal as well. But if they are different, it still might be that the energy is the same -- either by coincidence (for some specific values), or because there is some deeper underlying connection. And this is indeed the case.

Comment: @BobD My question is a comparison of energy consumed by people. When the masses of the two objects were different, I thought that if a person pushed an object at the same force and distance, the kinetic energy of the object would be the same regardless of the mass. (If the amount of work done to an object is the same, so is the energy consumed by a person.) Is there an error in my opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that if someone pushed objects of different mass by the same force and distance, the energy consumed by the person would be the same.

Yes, the energy imparted to each object would be the same regardless of their mass, as work done only depends on the force and the distance over which the force is applied.

You might be getting mixed up with a few things

1. Power output: it will take longer to push the object with more mass the same distance as the object with less mass with the same force. And as I am sure you could think by example, the time it takes to push something will impact how much you feel like you need to expend
2. "Effort": While we can consider work done, this is not the whole picture. For example, you will feel fatigued holding an object at rest even though no work is being done on the object. Your muscles still use energy to "operate", even if no work is being done.

> Is it true that the energy consumed by the person is different?

There is more to this question than meets the eye. I am sure a sufficiently detailed answer would need to look specifically at the pushing technique, time of pushing, and much more; there isn't a singular way for a person to exert a given force, especially if the force is met with different amounts of inertia.

Comment: When a person pushes objects of different mass (Person pushes M1 and then the same person pushes objects at the same distance as the force, the kinetic energy of the person seen by the external stationary observer is the same. I understand up to here. But since they pushed objects of different masses, the later speeds of the two objects would be different. I haven't done the calculation, but in the above case, I think the kinetic energy of a person + the kinetic energy of an object will depend on the mass of the object, is it wrong?

Comment: When a person pushes an object, is the kinetic energy of the person the same as the kinetic energy of the object?

Comment: @NOHWHIREA *"When a person pushes an object, is the kinetic energy of the person the same as the kinetic energy of the object?"* Not necessarily. If the person and object have the same speed, they will only have the same kinetic energy if they have the same mass

Comment: @Biophysicst  If the same person pushes M1 and M2, which are objects of different mass, then the total kinetic energy will be different. If the energy consumed by a person is converted into kinetic energy, isn't it right that even if the mass of a person is the same, the energy consumed by a person depends on the mass of the object being pushed?

Comment: There is a misleading expression in the above question. It means that the force and distance applied to a person are constant. The net force applied to a person at this time is only the reaction force of the force that the person pushes the object, so the product of the reaction force and the distance will be the change in kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

Putting humans in the loop will not help you understand the basics of dynamics, as it is just not intuitive.

It's better to consider an abstract force pushing with $F$ for a distance $x$. The work done is:

$$ W = \int_0^x Fdx' = Fx'|^{x'=x}_{x'=0} = Fx$$

and that is going to be the kinetic energy of the object:

$$ T = W  = Fx$$

Notice how $m$ has not appeared in the equations.

If you want to understand how $m$ is involved, you can use either:

$$ T = \frac 1 2 m v^2 $$

or
$$ T = \frac{p^2}{2m} $$

I prefer the latter, as:

$$ p = \int_0^t Fdt' = Ft $$

so you just need to figure out $t$ using:

$$ a = \frac F m $$

Answer (score 1):

The described exercise is not completely clear so I'll answer for two cases.

**Case 1.** A person exerts force on M1 with one hand, and force on M2 with the other hand. Assuming the two forces are equal, the two masses will have different velocities. At some point they will be that much apart that the person will have to give up on one of the masses.

**Case 2.** One of the masses is stacked on the other mass and the person exerts force on one of the masses. Assuming there is enough friction between the two masses so that they do not slip, they will be moving at the same velocity. You can simplify this case as if two masses are one big object of mass M1+M2.

---

As for the energy consumption by the person, please note that energy as defined in physics (force over distance) is an abstract concept that does not directly apply to the world as you experience it. Here is a simple intuitive example:

- A heavy stone lies on the table for 100 years. There is a force that table exerts on the stone, but there is no movement and the energy as defined in physics is zero.
- Now you try holding still a heavy stone. There will definitely be some energy consumed by your muscles and at some point you will have to drop the stone.