# Where does this conservation of momentum gedankenexperiment go wrong?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, work

Inspired by [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/760130/).

> Let's say I'm standing on a frictionless ice rink right next to a $1kg$ block. I push the block with $1N$ force for a distance of $1m$. I do $1J$ of work, obviously. By Newton's 3rd law, the block also exerts a $1N$ force on me for a distance of $1m$, so it does $-1J$ of work on me. This reasoning seems airtight. So my kinetic energy is now $1J$, and the block's kinetic energy is also $1J$. I can now compute our speeds. If I have a mass of $100kg$, then $v_{me} = 0.14m/s$. Meanwhile $v_{block} = 1.41m/s$.

However, momentum must also be conserved:

$$m_{me}v_{me} = m_{block}v_{block}$$

This requirement is clearly violated by the calculated speeds above. What has gone wrong?

I feel like the most probable source of error is that the block does not do $-1J$ of work on me, but I can't figure out why the logic there is wrong. $W = F \cdot dS$, there is a force and there is a displacement in the direction of the force, so there should be work.

The other possibility is that by inserting a human (i.e. a non-rigid body) into the gedankenexperiment I somehow break conservation of momentum - but if so, why?

Comment: In case you're confused about the other answers, I added an edit explaining what's going on.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks. I figured it out after a brief moment of confusion. If I am gaining kinetic energy, then something must be exerting a force on me, and there is only one force. Since the amount of KE gained is fixed, that force must move by a displacement that is not 1m. But my arm is extending by 1m, so something else must be moving by a smaller amount, and that something is obviously the center of mass. In essence, it's a non-rigid body effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors. First, you flipped a sign: the block does *negative* work on you, so your energy is lower than before.

But how is that possible? Wouldn't that mean your final kinetic energy has to be negative? That's the second error: the work done on a system changes its *total* energy, not just the kinetic energy associated with the motion of the center of mass. Your total energy goes down by 1 Joule, because you gain 0.01 Joules of kinetic energy (as required by momentum conservation) and lose 1.01 Joules of chemical energy in your muscles.

But if you have to account for changes of internal energy, then how can energy conservation be applied usefully here? How could one know ahead of time that your muscles lose 1.01 Joules of chemical energy? The answer is that in many real-world situations energy conservation *isn't* a useful quantitative tool. In physics we tend to focus on situations where our tools work well.

---

If you're confused about the other two answers to this question, it's because they're using the concept of "center of mass (CM) work". Work is defined as the force times the displacement of the point the force is acting on, while CM work is defined as the force times the displacement of the CM of the whole object. CM work gives the change of CM kinetic energy, without including internal energy. Both types of work are valid concepts, though ordinary work tends to be useful much more often, and CM work is often conflated for work to keep things simple in middle school courses.

In this case, the explanation in terms of CM work is that you do a positive 1 Joule of CM work on the block, and the block does a positive 0.01 Joule of CM work on you. That's possible simply because there's no principle of conservation of CM kinetic energy.

Comment: Your answer does not even mention momentum. The essence of the question is that they could not see how to simultaneously conserve energy and momentum. Instead, you answered about a nitpick that is immediately edited out of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I had originally wanted to answer this to the OP's OP's OP, but I was too late then. This must be the real underlying confusion involved.

The issue is that it is basically impossible to push the constant force over fixed distance in that scenario. Remember, you are moving backwards as you push, so if you wanted to do that, you will have to, paradoxically, push harder as your arms extend.

What you can do is that you can exchange a certain total amount of momentum $p>0$. This takes momentum conservation into account automatically. The amount of KE in the final state is $\frac{p^2}{2M} + \frac{p^2}{2m}$. All of this energy is coming from stored food chemical potential energy in your muscles. Taking the object as lighter $m$ and positive in velocity, it will be moving at $+p/m$ whereas you will move at $-p/M$

By N3L the forces "object on you" and "you on object" is the same throughout time. Really, this is rate of transfer of momentum, which is, again, necessarily the same throughout time, even if this rate is varying in time.

This means that the only way for you and the object to be getting different energies, is for the distances the forces acted upon to differ. This is precisely the case. As easy way to see it is via power $P = \vec F \cdot \vec v$. You are heavier and thus move slower, over a shorter distance, as you push the object. So you get a smaller KE than the object. So, even in the ridiculous case whereby you insist upon constant force, you would get this behaviour.

i.e. you are not free to choose your traversed distance in this scenario.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of constant force at all - the same thing happens if we merely take the 1N of force to be an average of varying force over 1s rather than truly uniform over 1s.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie if the force is varying over time, and thus presumably over distance, then it is likely to distribute the energies differently, and then the person who is having the question would not be tempted to think that there is a paradox. I'm trying to give a universal solution that answers the core of the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, putting a human in the loop never helps. You have to resort to ATP, or chalk it up to "non-rigid bodies".

Why not have two masses $m$, $M$, where $M$ has an ideal spring-like thing with $F = kx^0$ attached to it. It's compressed by $L$.

When it expands, it pushes on $m$ and $M$ with $F=k$ for a distance:

$$ d = \frac M{M+m} L, $$
$$ D = \frac m{M+m} L $$

respectively, doing work (from energy stored in the spring):

$$ w = Fd = F\frac M{M+m} L ,$$
$$ W = FD = F\frac m{M+m} L $$

Each block has equal magnitude momentum:

$$ p = Ft $$

where $t$ is the time it takes to uncoil the spring-thing, which is computable from:

$$ x = \frac 1 2 a t^2 $$

with $a$ = $F/m$ or $F/M$ and $x = d$ or $D$, you get:

$$ t^2 = \frac{2L}F\frac{mM}{m+M} $$

which is symmetric in $m$ and $M$, as it should be. Now compute the kinetic energies (note: avoid velocity, it doesn't matter):

The small (large) masses' are:

$$ T_m = \frac{p^2}{2m} = \frac{(Ft)^2}{2m} = \frac{FLM}{m+M},$$
$$ T_M = \frac{p^2}{2M} = \frac{(Ft)^2}{2M} = \frac{FLm}{m+M}$$

which agrees with the work done by the spring-thing.

Very clear when the arm is just a machine, even though it's a non-rigid body, it's easy to see where the potential energy is stored.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the queries that have been asked can be resolved by being a bit more precise as to what is being written about.

In this example a statement of the system under consideration - "me", mass $M$,  and block, mass $m$.
Then a statement about the external forces acting on the system - no horizontal forces.

The human body is a complex entity and so it is best to reduce the human body into inert components - a massless bionic arm, looking like a spring which can exert constant forces and powered by chemical energy, attached to the rest of the body.

All components of the system start from rest.

The arm exerts constant forces on the block and the body and the block and the body exert forces on the arm (Newton's third law) which must be equal in magnitude and opposite in direction as the arm which is massless can have net force acting on it.

Thus the forces exerted by the arm on the block and the body must also be equal in magnitude $F$ and opposite in direction.

If the forces acts for a time $t$ the magnitude of the impulse on the block and the body $F\,t$ must be the same but in opposite directions.
As impulse equals change in momentum the change in momentum of the block and the body must be the same but in opposite directions and that means that momentum is conserved.

As there are no external forces present the centre of mass of the system does not move and the distances moved by the block and the body must be inversely proportional to their masses.

If the block moves a distance $d$ relative to the centre of mass of the system then the body moves a distance $d\, \dfrac mM$ relative to the centre of mass of the system.

Thus the total work done by the arm is $F\,d\, ({\text{on block}})\, + F\, d\, \dfrac mM\, ({\text{on body}})$.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's 3rd law says that because you exert a 1N force on the block it exerts a 1N force on you (in the opposite direction). It does *not* say that the distances you and the block travel are the same. The forces will be exerted for the same time, but that is not the same thing. If your mass is 100kg you will move 1cm while the block moves 1m. This will allow for your momentum and the block's momentum to be equal but opposite.

Note that in this analysis your body is thought of as a single unit, acting as though it is all at your centre of mass. Any movement of your hand is regarded as unimportant because its mass is so small compared with the rest of your body.

Note also that in the formula $W = F \cdot dS$, the $dS$ refers to the motion of the centre of mass. There is often energy put into rotation or internal movement, but this formula is not about that.

In practice, when working out situations such as the one you described, conservation of momentum is used and energy is worked out from the resulting motion.

Comment: *It does not say that the distances you and the block travel are the same.* If I'm in contact with the block (necessary to exert force on it) then the block must be in contact with me, and if my arm moves 1m, wouldn't the reaction force also move 1m?

Comment: @Allure it cannot be the same, and that is what we are telling you. You have to separate between the part of the motion of your arm that is due to the block moving, and the part that is due to your own self moving.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Can you explain why they cannot be the same, given the argument in my comment above? If my arm moves by 1m, then the reaction force ought to also move by 1m. I don't see how these two can be different. knzhou's explanation seems to make much more sense, the reaction force does move by 1m, but I do not get 1J of kinetic energy because the sign is different.

Comment: @Allure I gave a fuller answer before Peter even gave an answer. In this problem you have to choose the frame of reference relative to ground, or else nothing makes sense. Work done is force times "distance travelled by CoM". As you push the block, your arm moves by the sum of the distance travelled by CoM of block and the CoM of you.

Comment: @Allure as for why you cannot use any other frame of reference, it is because if you choose the frame of reference whereby you are stationary, yes, your arm extended 1m and thus the block moved the entire 1m, but now the incredibly heavy ice skating rink is moving, with tremendous KE. The only upside is that you would have transferred all the energy to the block and left none for yourself, because distance travelled by you is zero in your own reference frame. It is not inertial, so there is no saving it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Start with two bodies [A][B] in contact. [A] has a mass of 100 kg, [B] has a mass of 1 kg.

They apply a 1 N force on each other.  1 fraction of a second later, they are not in contact.  They are no longer able to apply a contact force to each other.

But wait, you say, can't they act on each other at a distance?  And don't we care about center of mass?

Sure they can apply force at a distance.  But then the force isn't applied *at the location of [B]*, it is applied on each at each object's location!

And if we care about center of mass, again, even if they stay in contact, the force then needs to be calculated at [A]s center of mass, not at the point of contact.

When 1 N of force is applied to [B] by [A], [B] applies 1 N back to [A].  If the 1 N of force is applied while [B] moves 1 meter, **[A] does not move 1 meter** in this period.  [A] moves 100x less, about 1 cm.

So 1J of work is done by [A] upon [B], while only 0.01 J of work is done by [B] upon [A] because [A] moves 100x less for the same momentum transfer.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to the other comments, which generally do a good job of making the mathematical case that the block hasn't done 1J of work on you, I would like to add my personal visualization of the situation. Hopefully you'll find the mathematical answers somewhat more intuitive if you imagine the scenario just slightly differently.

I found that the presentation (standing on a frictionless ice rink) confusing at first, since it's natural to assume that if you're standing on something, there's some amount of friction there to allow you to keep your balance. So let's put you on your back, lying down with your legs curled to your chest.

> Let's say you're *lying down* on a frictionless ice rink, with your legs curled and a 1-kilogram weight (make it a 1-liter bottle of water for argument's sake) next to your foot. Now kick your legs out, extending them fully in the space of one and a half seconds. How fast is the water bottle moving, and how quickly are you moving?

In this framing, it's easy to see that you won't wind up with a lot of forward momentum. After all, if you take the water bottle out of the equation, it's easy to imagine kicking your legs back and forth without moving at all (e.g., by counterbalancing any off-balance inertial forces with your arms). The frictionless ice-rink is just like being in outer space, and you can't swim through outer space. If you want to move, you have to jettison some mass.

When you kick the water bottle away, you extend your legs through a meter, and could easily exert a constant force on it the whole time. But extending your legs doesn't alter your total position. The position of your center of gravity changes very little. Thus, even though you've done 1J of mechanical work on the water bottle, the bottle does much less than 1J of mechanical work on you.